# Configure automatic equivalent to git stash git apply when changing branches

Tags: git

Right now I have locally a credential file that I use locally to test my changes.

set_env.py defines environment variables that I use to log in a distant app

As I don't want to actually push the credentials, I pushed a dummy file which basically does nothing (as the environment variables are supposed to be already defined on the test server for example).

However, since I have a dummy file pushed to my branch, set_env.py is considered staged and I cannot change branches

`git checkout other_branch`

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    config/set_env.py
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

A solution would simply to stash this file every time I want to switch branches (assuming I have no other modified staged and non-commited file)

```
git stash
git checkout other_branch
git stash apply
```

However it becomes cumberstone to have to type 3 commands each time I want to change the branch I'm working on. Is there a way to tell git to consider this file as unstaged from now on ? (without deleting the file on the next commit)

Edit: @phd answer seems the most straightforward, however it does only work if I don't have any other staged uncommited file. Is there a solution where I could do what I want and still stash other files ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create an alias:

```
git config alias.stco "!f() { git stash && git checkout "$@" && git stash apply ; }; f"
```

Usage:

```
git stco other_branch
```

PS. `stco` for "stash and checkout".

Comment: This seem to work, however it is only possible if I don't have any other staged uncommited file in my branch